# Only need to process specific columns in my Spark DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've been working with this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32357226/how-to-vectorize-dataframe-columns-for-ml-algorithms) but I have more specific needs.

I need to select only columns that start with "cat". I not able to determine how to select columns based on a pattern. I don't need to filter the dataframe, just select only the columns with names that start with the pattern.

```
val transformers: Array[PipelineStage] = df.select("cat*").columns.map(
  cname =>
    new StringIndexer()
      .setInputCol(cname)
      .setOutputCol(s"${cname}_index")
  )

val stages: Array[PipelineStage] = transformers

val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(stages)
val model = pipeline.fit(df)
```

This code yields an error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'cat*' given input columns: [cat3, cat7, cat25,...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you selecting from the dataframe at all to get the columns ? Why not just filter over all the names :

```
val transformers: Array[PipelineStage] = df.columns.filter(_.startsWith("cat")).map(
  cname =>
    new StringIndexer()
      .setInputCol(cname)
      .setOutputCol(s"${cname}_index")
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an easy one. You just filter on your columns that starts with "cat" as followed :

```
val transformers: Array[PipelineStage] = df.select("cat*").columns.filter(_.startsWith("cat")).map(
          cname =>
           new StringIndexer()
              .setInputCol(cname)
              .setOutputCol(s"${cname}_index")
    )
```

Comment: Im sorry for a possible typo. I'm on my phone.

Comment: I wasn't sure above ut that as the docs seemed to indicate filter acts on rows instead of columns. Let me try that. Thanks!

Comment: If you deconstruct the code, the columns method returns a collect on which you can apply a filter (similar to the one you use on RDDs but not the same) then a map.