# How to specify multiple columns in xgboost.trainWithDataframe when using spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, xgboost

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WP9DP.png)

This is the api doc present in xgboost.com , it seems that I can just set only one column as the "featureCol" .

Answer (score 1):

As with any ML `Estimator` on Spark, this one expects `inputCol` to be a `Vector` of assembled features. Before you apply the `Estimator`, you should use tools from `org.apache.spark.ml.feature` to extract, transform and assemble feature vector.

You can check [How to vectorize DataFrame columns for ML algorithms?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32357226) for example `Pipeline`.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but,I do  transformed the features by using org.apche.spark.ml.feafure for oneHotEncode and countVector . And I get multiple  columns now , how can I apply them to the estimator  ?

Comment: @SteveYN [`VectorAssembler`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#vectorassembler)